# How To Filter Out Lambdas with the AWS Cli with tags?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli

So I know I can grab all lambda functions via this command in text/csv form:

```
aws lambda list-functions --region us-east-1 --query 'Functions[].FunctionName' --output text
```

But I want to list all the functions with their relevant tags associated with the lambda. How do I do it? I want to output all of them into a CSV/text form, such as:

```
Name Tag_1 Tag2    
{lambda_name} {tag_1} {tag_2}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can combine [list-functions](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/list-functions.html) and [list-tags](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/list-tags.html)

An example:

> aws lambda list-functions | jq -r ".Functions[].FunctionArn" | xargs
> -I {} aws lambda list-tags --resource {} --query '{"{}":Tags}'

Comment: Do you need to specify an output at the end? I tried this and it loops and loops

Comment: or without jq: 
`aws lambda list-functions --query 'Functions[].[FunctionArn]' --output text | xargs -I {} aws lambda list-tags --resource {} --query '{"{}":Tags}'`

Answer (score 1):

You would first of all need to call `aws lambda list-functions`, then save the results, and then call `aws lambda list-tags --resource 'YourLambda'` for all of your retrieved functions. Unfortunately there is no other way currently.