# List of AWS lambda functions deployed from my IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How is it possible to get a list of AWS functions deployed by my IAM. The problem here is that our organization has over 4000 lambda functions so I don't need list of lambda functions in our account, rather ones I've created.

Comment: You can try exporting ALL the cloudtrail events you have and analyze them locally. Other than that you have no options since Lambda (and basically all services for that matter) do not store the info who created them because why should they!?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a viable option we have 12-15 teams (at different times) working on our product for several years already, how could I figure out which lambdas are obsolete and can be safely removed. Also I think answering your question "why should they?" with my (original) question will not be considered as question to question answer as I was first with mine :) In any case thank you.

Comment: Yeah, you are out of options. 12-15 teams should not work within the same AWS account to begin with, that is risky as hell. And as to "how could I figure out which lambdas are obsolete" - you absolutely cannot. You can check the cloudwatch metrics to see which ones have not been invoked in the last year but maybe there is a lambda deployed for a corner case that is used only every 1.5 years... Resource should have naming schemas associating them with specific teams or be tagged or ... but if you did not have those in place already you simply have no alternatives right now.

Comment: In the absence of good account management and tagging hygiene, CloudTrail events  may be your best hope. Going forward, here's some help for [organizing AWS accounts](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/getting-started/best-practices/) and [tagging best practices](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-tagging-best-practices.pdf) that your organization should begin to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a wrong concept to group your lambdas.... I suggest you use a tag and then list all the lambdas, query the tags and filter by that:

[How To Filter Out Lambdas with the AWS Cli with tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66991343/how-to-filter-out-lambdas-with-the-aws-cli-with-tags)